# Travis CI, pip, and pygame

Tags: pygame, virtualenv, pip, travis-ci

I am trying to setup a project with Travis CI. Project also uses pygame. I had multiple attempts to set it up - but it seem to be failing.

The closest I got was following:

`.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"
install:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
    - sudo apt-get install mercurial
script:
    - nosetests tests/*.py
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Twisted==13.2.0
coverage==3.7.1
nose==1.3.0
hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.1.0
```

Travis CI downloads the pygame package, but the installation hangs:

https://travis-ci.org/ruslanosipov/space/builds/19142164#L390

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution was as follows:

Create separate .travis_requirements.txt without the pygame.

Change `.travis.yml` as follows:

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get update -qq
    - sudo apt-get build-dep -qq python-pygame
    - sudo apt-get install -qq python-pygame
install:
    - pip install -r .travis_requirements.txt
script:
    - nosetests tests/*.py
virtualenv:
    system_site_packages: true
```

Main change is using "system_site_packages" setting and installing pygame via apt-get.